# Can an unmanaged switched be used for /30?

Tags: networking

Can an unmanaged switch be used for /30? If yes, how do I go about it?

To clear things up:

I have DSL, 2 PCs running Windows, 1 unmanaged switch (netgear fs105), and no router.

I just want to give each PC a separate static IP to access the internet, and I see my ISP's offering /30, but I have no idea what to do with it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: A switch is a lower layer than IP.  It doesn't matter what IP settings you use.  It works on MAC addresses.

Comment: The answer to the first question is: "yes". And the answer to the second question is: "it depends". Seriously, you haven't told us nearly enough about your setup for anybody to give you any more than a one word answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I'm new to all this. What else can I tell you about my setup? I have 2 PCs running windows, and I'm just trying to buy a /30 from my ISP, but I have no idea how to assign these IPs to my PCs.

Comment: Do you really need your own /30 ? You are saying that you have no idea what to do with it, and I don't see any use case for the general public where you would need one static IP per computer.

Comment: I need 2 residential IPs to access the internet, so I can't use VPNs. For now, ordering a /30 from my ISP is the cheapest option. Unfortunately I know nothing about networking, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Quentin The general public might not need a static IP address per computer. But they still need an IP address per computer. In the past you would usually get one or more dynamic addresses - but not anymore. Some ISPs have started moving all customers who do not rent static IP addresses behind a NAT444 setup.

Comment: @kasperd You're right about my ISP limiting each account to just 1 PPPoE session. Gone are the good old days. Thanks for replying. I'll try superuser now.

Comment: @kasperd Indeed, but they don't need a public IP per computer. It is 2015, with the IPv4 address exhaustion, is seems unreasonable to recommend this for the general public. NAT are deployed for this very reason. If there is no need to allocate a public IP for a given set of devices, then why reserve 4 times the required amount of addresses ? He may also spare a little because he won't need to buy a router now, but it is not scalable at all. Adds 2 smartphones and one tablet to his config and he will need to request a /27.

Comment: @Heisenburger "I need 2 residential IPs to access the internet, so I can't use VPNs." In fact you don't. You need a router and one address. This address is used by your router, and the latter translates public address to local addresses  (see NAT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). It allows to have a (almost) unlimited number of computers in your private network with only one public IP.

Comment: @Quentin NAT is a hack, which breaks a lot of things. If somebody wants a network that just works, they shouldn't be using NAT. Your math isn't entirely accurate either. Five devices won't need a /27, a /29 will be sufficient for five devices.

Comment: @kasperd Indeed, my bad for the miscalculation (i should'nt make math before my morning tea). But my point remains, it is not scalable at all. And yes, NAT are hacks created as a temporary solution to overcome IP exhaustion, and dates back to ... 1994. In 2015, the problem is even worse. The real solution would be to switch entirely to IPV6. And Heisenburger just wants to "connect to the internet", not "connect the internet to him". He would'nt see any difference if he used a NAT.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, IPv4 is not scalable and never was. The only reason the average user don't see a difference between a network with NAT and one without is this: They don't know what problems caused by NAT looks like. And most of them have never seen a network without NAT. But you certainly do have a point with IPv6. Instead of asking for a /30 he should probably ask for a /29 and a /56. (Anybody who never asked their ISP for a /56 is part of the problem, because the ISP will use them as an excuse for not doing what they should be doing.)

Comment: Given that Heisenburger was mixing layer 2 and layer 3 concepts I assumed that he is an average user. As you said, an average user won't see the difference if he is behind a NAT or not (and he get scalability for free). An advanced user knows how to get around a NAT. For these two reasons I won't advocate a public IPV4 range allocation for a home connection (I run a server at home behind a NAT for my  personal use, and I have yet to find something that I can't solve via port forwarding).

Comment: @Heisenburger Out of pure curiosity, how much (if at all) does your ISP charge for a /30 or a /29 ? I have never seen this where I live, but I have also never asked.

Comment: @Quentin An average user will experience problems caused by NAT, they just won't know the problems are caused by NAT. And most of the problems will appear to be transient and disappear when retrying, making it even more difficult to realize the connection. But they will still experience problems and get annoyed by them, so they are not getting scalability for free.

Comment: @kasperd Why not, but what problem specifically created by the NAT are you talking about ? Especially if the problem is transient, I would suspect more a hardware problem of the crappy router provided by the ISP than a flaw of the NAT concept itself. Could you make all this more clear to the people reading this by giving a factual example ?

Comment: @Quentin My ISP (Teksavvy) charges $5/mo for /30 and $10/mo for /29. I was going for /30 without knowing its limintations. Getting /29 now.

Comment: @Quentin The most common problem is connection tracking entries being timed out prematurely by the NAT. That is far from the only problem, but many of the other problems depend on which protocols you are using and which NAT. And if you don't have the necessary access to monitor traffic on the outside of the NAT (as is often the case), it may be impossible to figure out exactly what the problem with that particular NAT device is.

Comment: @Heisenburger Out of curiosity: What do they charge for a /56?

Comment: @kasperd Unfortunately they offer only /30 /29 /28.

Comment: @kasperd I am not really convinced that it is an important problem for Average Joe. A NAT will not timeout a port association while it is being used, and when it is not actively used (i.e. no packets are sent) the server/other peer should/will timeout it, especially when it is serving thousands of users. It is only a matter of time, and maybe the NAT in question will be a bit faster to interrupt connections, but this problem is most likely to appear appear also without NAT for the kind of services the average user will use.

Comment: @Heisenburger Thanks. It's really uncommon here (I live in France), and I have never thought about asking for it because I am comfortable with NAT an I prefer to manage the addressing in my private network myself.

Comment: @Quentin Not all connections are equal. Servers know better than to blindly close all connections which have been idle for some fixed amount of time. And if the server does close a connection, it gets done cleanly such that both client and server knows the connection was closed. If a connection is timed out by a NAT, it is likely to stall such that both client and server will keep trying to use it. And connections being timed out by a NAT can happen even to connections which are actively being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fundamental flaw in what you're saying.  You're talking about 2 PCs.  For that, you don't need a /30.  You need a /29.

If you don't care about Internet access, then you can just use one of the many addresses provided to you by RFC 1918.

If you do care about Internet access, then you need 3 addresses: one for each of your two PCs, and one for the ISP.  A /30 provides 4 addresses, 2 of which are "unusable" by common IPv4 standards, so that leaves you with 2 addresses when you need 3.  So, you'll end up needing to get a /29, which doubles the total amount of addresses, which means you are provided with 8 addresses, two of which will be "unusable" by common IPv4 standards, and one of which will be for the ISP, leaving you with 5 usable addresses for your devices (such as your PCs).

Now, an unmanaged switch will handle any number of IPs, because an unmanaged switch uses MAC-48 addresses to communicate via Ethernet.  (I'm talking about the simplest/cheapest "unmanaged switch" I can think of.)  Then, the Internet Protocol (IP) communication uses the successful Ethernet communication.  Since the switch's only job is to handle the Ethernet connection, the switch really doesn't do anything special to handle the IP addresses.  So, Joel Coehoorn's answer was correct in that respect.  However, you're plan to use a /30 needs some more forethought.

In theory, a /30 could be useful for two PCs if you're planning to give that /30 to a device, such as a firewall (which might be build into a "modem", such as a "cable modem" or a "DSL modem"), which provides NAT services.  There are some drawbacks to that, but that could be done.  Using that sort of setup, you would have the firewall (which is providing NAT) provide "port forwarding" of a specified port number to a PC.  So, for example, you could have TCP port 80 be redirected to your first PC, and that would allow your first PC to run a web server.  However, you would not have a second public IP address for TCP port 80 to go to your second PC.  As long as you're not running the same service on both PCs, this sort of limit may be acceptable.  Just beware of that limitation.  If you don't want to put up with the requirement of dealing with such limitations, then get a /29 so you needn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks so much for such a detailed answer! You just saved me from a lot of pain. Getting /29 now.

Comment: What do you mean by "one (address) will be for for the ISP" ? The ISP is providing him addresses for his use, he don't need to care about what the company is using on its side. And as in my other comment, I advise against this solution. Add 2 smartphone, one tablet and one xbox to this setup and he will need to require a /27.

Comment: Quentin: Your bad math continues.  If he adds 2 smartphones, one tablet, and 1 xbox to his 2 PCs, that is 6 devices, so he would need a /28 (16 addresses - 3 = 13 supported), not a /27 (32 addresses - 3 = 29 supported).  Also, subnet's "default gateway" needs to be in the subnet so communication with the Internet works.  Since the subnet's default gateway will be the address used by the ISP's equipment, one address of the subnet is reserved for that purpose, and is unavailable for customer's to assign to one of customer's devices (assuming that working Internet connectivity is desired).

Comment: @TOOGAM Indeed, same bad math, same context, same point still valid : not scalable. Thanks for the explanation, it is more clear now. And it makes the ratio worse than I thought : using 8 public addresses instead of the 1 required.

Answer (score 1):

If you only use one vlan, an unmanaged switch will work and it doesn't matter what the / boundary is.

Managed switches are important when you need to control settings for individual ports such as vlan assignment, speed, enabled/disabled, etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Let's say I order /30 from my ISP and they give me 2 static IPs. What should I do next to assign each IP to each PC? (a hint on what to google would be really helpful too).

Comment: You'll need a router that can do 1:1 NAT, not just a switch.